# JPA ManyToMany anotation for not load all items in set

Tags: java, jpa

I have `User` class and `BattleReportILogItem` class. This class (`User`, `BattleReportILogItem`) are `@Entity`.

`User` have **0..N** `BattleReportILogItem`.

**USER**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_USER)
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long userId;

        @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinTable(name = DomainConstant.VIEW_USER_BATTLE_LOGS, joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_BATTLE_REPORT_ID)})
        private Set<BattleReportILogItem> setOfBattleLogs = new HashSet<>();

....(other stuff, get and set methods...)
```

**BattleReportILogItem**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_BATTLE_REPORT)
public class BattleReportILogItem implements Serializable {



      @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_BATTLE_REPORT_ID)
        private Long BattleReportILogItemId;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "setOfBattleLogs")
        private Set<User> setOfBattleLogs = new HashSet<>();

        ....(other stuff, get and set methods...)
```

The problem is, that I load `User` program loads all data in `private Set<BattleReportILogItem> setOfBattleLogs = new HashSet<>();`. This mean `1 000 000 000` items in my set `setOfBattleLogs`. I don't want load data to this `set`. For load data i have `BattleReportLogItemDao` **DAO**.

Is there any solution how to **NOT LOAD DATA** to my `set`?

I hope, you understand me... :-))

Thank you for your help.

EDIT `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="com.donutek"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="true" />

            <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EDIT 2:**
For load user I am using the code:

```
@Override
public User findByEmail(String email) {
    TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM " + User.class.getSimpleName() + " u WHERE u.email = :uemail", User.class);
    q.setParameter("uemail", email);
    try {
        return q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: @Bunti Hi, I edit post, look at update.

Comment: Default loading is LAZY for an M-N so won't be loaded unless you request it. Alternatively use entityGraphs for more control over loading. Since you don't post the code you use for loading objects then no further comment is possible

Comment: How do you see that all data is loaded when you load `User` object. Are you using debugger to see loaded data in which case another query will be used to fetch all associated data, or do you see additional query being issued to fetch `BattleReportILogItem` when a `User` object is loaded?

Comment: I update my post and I add code from `UserDao` for load User object.

Comment: When I load data I am using code `System.out.println(user.toString());` for simple debug :-) and in this `toString` I can see data.

Comment: If your `toString()` method in `User` object references `BattleReportILogItem ` entity set that could trigger its associations to be loaded. Further you should set `hibernate.format_sql=true` and `hibernate.show_sql=true` and remove `BattleReportILogItem` reference from `User` toString method. Then I think that that would fix your issue.

Comment: @Bunti SO.... Data are loaded when I need it? Really? I think, all data are loaded in method `findByEmail`. All `User` object contains `setOfBattleLogs  set` .

Comment: Did you see additional query issued to fetch `BattleReportILogItem` when you load `User` object even after removing references in `toString()` method ?

Comment: @Bunti **LOL**. It works. In querty is not...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter fetchtype Lazy. Now your strategy seems to be Eager.

Comment: `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` it is same, it load all data.

Comment: Taken from HIbernate docs, `By default, Hibernate uses lazy select fetching for collections and lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.` See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-lazy)

Comment: Ok, my bad then. Could you provide the dao method which does the fetch ? You simply use the entity manager ?